# Cannot boot after installing Ubuntu - Do not have access to any system

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, system-installation, windows

I installed Ubuntu after installing Windows 10 on my system. After the installation, my BIOS/UEFI can not boot. No boot device is found, although I loaded up the boot manager and selected the right drive.

I think that my problem is that I installed Ubuntu and Windows on the same drive and now my system does not know how to boot up. I cannot boot into any system. But if I try to install Ubuntu again, I can get to the the point where I have to create new partitions. It clearly says Windows 10 and Ubuntu, so why can I not boot? I do not have access to any OS.

Edit: I did some research and found out that my bootloader is probably corrupted. I am fairly new to OS-installation in general (I have found a different article regarding my problem, but could not figure out how to solve it).

Edit2: Your recommended software did not work for me.

Comment: What recommended software?   Please be specific, and was windows 10 and unspecified Ubuntu release (did you try and appropriate release??) both installed in the same mode?  Your vague message seems like you're trying to boot in secure mode, and I wonder if you changed a bios setting to achieve install, then after your install changed a setting back causing the installed system to be unable to boot.

Answer (score 0):

Make a bootable drive of windows and after booting from the pendrive select repair your computer and then advance option then select command promt then run the commands 
Bootrec /fixmbr
Bootrec /fixboot
Bootrec /rebuildbcd
It will possibly make your windows boot

If not try installing ubuntu again with custom installation option and format the partion where you want to install ubuntu in ext4 format nad bootpoint type / that’s all.
I recommend you to install ubuntu in other drive partition than windows

Comment: okay, should I wipe ubuntu from my system?

Comment: No need to wipe